# Matlab create vectorized sequence

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to construct a function that accepts input n and gives the vector

```
[n n-1 n-2 ... n-n, n-1 n-2 ... n-n, ..., n-n]

//Example 
input :  n=3 
output : [3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0]
```

I know how to do this using loops, but I'm looking for a clever way to do it in MATLAB

Comment: I do not get how the sequence goes fron n-n ... n-n in the end

Comment: @Wajahat I have added some commas, I hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `repmat` to repeat the matrix a few times, and then select only the triangular part by means of `tril`. Like this:

```
n=3;
x=repmat(n:-1:0,1,n+1);
result=x(tril(ones(n+1))>0)
```

Or in one line:

```
n=3;
getfield(repmat(n:-1:0,1,n+1),{reshape(tril(ones(n+1))>0,1,(n+1)^2)})
```

The result of this function is the desired output:

```
result =

     3     2     1     0     2     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: I think you need `(n+1)^2` in place of 16

Comment: Yes, I pasted my draft too quick ;)

Comment: Nice solution, I suppose one step could still be taken out by replacing the last line with: `result=x(tril(true(n+1)))`

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't gotten any answers, here's a way to do it:

```
N = 3;
x = repmat(N:-1:0,1,N+1)-cumsum(repmat([1 zeros(1,N)],1,N+1))+1
x = x(x>=0)
x =
    3   2   1   0   2   1   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Or else: `x = mod((N+1)^2-1:-1:0,4) - ceil((1:((N+1)^2))/(N+1)) + 1` in a very similar vein

Comment: Perhaps a matter of taste, but I would go for something like this in the middle line: `repmat(N:-1:0,N+1,1)'-repmat(1:N+1,N+1,1)+1`